# What are the basic commands for ufw firewall in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, firewall, port, ufw

I want to setup ufw firewall in ubuntu.

Please list some basic commands that I need to learn to operate it via termianl.

Comment: `man ufw` ?????

Comment: it would give a huge list of information, which would be like arabic for a newbie, I have listed the most basic commands

Comment: [What types of question should I avoid asking ?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Install the application ufw

```
apt install ufw
```

Start firewall

```
enable ufw
```

Stop firewall

```
disable ufw
```

List of current running processes

```
ufw app list
```

Make rules to allow a certain process through firewall

```
ufw allow process1
```

Make rules to allow only incoming traffic of a certain process through firewall

```
ufw allow in process4
```

Make rules to allow only outgoing traffic of a certain process through firewall

```
ufw allow out process5
```

Make rules to block a certain process through firewall

```
ufw deny process2
```

View current list of processes being controlled by firewall and the associated rules for those processess

```
ufw status
```

View listening ports of an active process

```
ufw app info process3
```